# Updating iOS app jumping from 1.0 to 1.x missing all update in the middle

Tags: ios, core-data

I have not been able to track this down with any of the official Xcode instruments.

I am not trying to solve any particular problem. I wanted to know, for a deeper understanding, what happens, from a CoreData+sqllite point of view, when the user miss an update, and update a future version.

I mean app 1.0 is installed, then 1.1 is released with change in its xcdatamodel, but for any reason, user didn't update it.
Then a few days (or weeks) later 1.2 is out with change in its xcdatamodel, and user update the app. Or worst, he only update at version 1.x.
In the meantime, the app has not been removed from the device, so the documents folder is still there.

My understanding is: when an app is updated, at start up the model is updated too.
Just because a sqllite database cannot have column renamed, plus other restrictions, I suppose a new set of tables, if needed, are created and populated with old data, then old tables get dropped.

So, with the xcdatamodel containing all previous versions, is iOS traversing all the chain up to the latest version updating the model step by step, or is it smart enough to jump directly to the latest version ?

Comment: Whether you can jump straight to the latest version depends on what changes you made in each model version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a newly updated app with Core Data, iOS will look at the previously active Core Data model, and the new Core Data model. It will make its changes based on all the versions in between. If there were no versions in between, it just does what it normally does. If there are versions in between (because, like you said, the user skips an app update), it applies all of those versions and makes the changes based on those.

So, to actually answer your question: yes, the system is smart enough to do that. As long as you make sure that it can migrate from one version to the next (be it lightweight or using a mapping model), the system will take care of the rest.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are referring to NSManagedObjectModel versioning.

That is a mute question. Of course you maybe could jump to another version and it might work. Why not just go through the sequence of versions as described in the API documentation?

You could parse the core data managed object model file, which is simple XML and try to manipulate it... But why even waste time on something like that? What does it have to do with the model being "smart"=?

Yes, you could cross a street blindfolded and *not* be run over by a car.

Comment: I don't think you understand his question. Users can always skip a version of an app, that's not something the developer can't help. His question is: if 1.1 ships with model version `x`, and 1.2 ships with `y`, how does iOS make the migration to 1.2 from 1.0?

Comment: I thought he is talking about NSManagedObjectModel versions.

Comment: The way I read it, he is asking how the system handles migration if some model version was never active on that particular device (which could happen if the user decides to not install an update).